# index of in Arraylist<ABC> compare with other Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am trying to find the index of an element in an ArrayList based on the value of one of the properties, but it is always giving me -1.

```
//returnABClinklist method returns ABC linked list and i cannot use index of on linked list so am trying to convert it to arraylist
List<ABC> temp=new ArrayList<ABC>(someMethod.returnABClinklist());      
List<XYZ> other=new ArrayList<XYZ>();
```

Lets say `ABC` has 3 fields (`rollnum`, `name`, `state`) and `XYZ` has 5 fields, 3 of which are in common with `ABC` (`rollnum`, `name`, `state`, `secondname`, `dob`). I want it iterate through one list and find each corresponding element in the other list, based on their `rollnum` values being the same. My goal is to then fill out the other corresponding fields (`name` and `state`). Here's what I tried:

```
Iterator<ABC> itr = abcList.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
  ABC tempABC=itr.next();
  int index = xyzList.indexOf(tempABC.rollnum()); //this always comes -1
}
```

The problem is that `indexOf()` is always returning -1. Can someone help with my implementation?

***Actual working snippet***

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class testLists {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<XYZ> temp=new ArrayList<XYZ>(); 
        List<ABC> other=new ArrayList<ABC>();

        ABC ab=new ABC();
        ABC ab1=new ABC();
        ab.rollnum=111;
        ab.name="MAK";
        other.add(ab);

        ab1.rollnum=222;
        ab1.name="DAK";
        other.add(ab1);

        XYZ abd=new XYZ();
        XYZ abd1=new XYZ();

        abd1.nameDB="MAK";
        abd1.rollnumDB=111;
        temp.add(abd1);

        abd.nameDB="PONTY";
        abd.rollnumDB=456;
        temp.add(abd);

         Iterator<XYZ> itr=temp.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()){
            XYZ tempXYZ=itr.next();
            int index=other.indexOf(tempXYZ.getRollnumDB()); //this always comes -1
            other.get(index) //get the data a
            //add more values to the tempXYZ 
            });
    }
}
```

POJO

```
public class ABC {

    int rollnum;
    String name;
    String state;
    public int getRollnum() {
        return rollnum;
    }
    public void setRollnum(int rollnum) {
        this.rollnum = rollnum;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    }
    public String getState() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setState(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**NOTE: tried implementing equals in my XYZ pojo but still no luck**

Comment: @JohnKugelman:Sir please add this to any java program with pvsm it will execute.Just hoping someone could help quickly or i can generate the pojo's and paste here.

Comment: Yes, you can, and should, provide a minimal, cmplete and verifiable example.

Comment: @JBNizet: :) As you say sir, give me 5 mins updating.

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to do, please?

Comment: other is a List<ABC>. You're calling other.indexOf() with an int as argument. A List<XYZ> doesn't contain integers. So it will always return -1. You can't find the index of a banana in a box of apples, because a box of apples never contains bananas. It contains apples.

Comment: @JBNizet: XYZ have a field int rollnum, is there any way that i can pull the values from other and store in ABC instance and use its values to push to XYZ while iterating one by one.I know that this indexOf will not work on collection of POJO without extra code.

Comment: @JBNizet: List of Banana and List of Apple have a field named price,Some banana's are very good looking and tasty so there price is high and some apple are bad quality so there price is low.So in these two apple and banana list at some point the price of a banana is equal to price of apple, i just need to pull that pair and then polish them :) Thanks :)

Comment: Sure, you can loop through your list, and find the apples that have the price you want. Or use list.stream().filter(...) to do just that. But you can't do that with indexOf(), because indexOf(), as documented, looks for the first element that is **equal** to the argument of the method.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks , I think got my answer.It's not possible with indexOf. I was just trying to avoid loop :\ . Also we are still behind, on java 6 :P so no stream :)

Comment: You should have found the answer by just reading the javadoc of the method. Or by applying common sense: how would the lid know that it has to look for the price field of the apple to compare it with the price passed as argument? And anyway, indexOf() does use a loop. It's not faster than the loop you'll create by yourself.

Comment: @JBNizet: was in denial mode :) expects some magical tips on SO :D anyway using a loop now.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `indexOf` is something which is hidden inside an `XYZ` object instance, but it is not of type `XYZ`. In your case you have to iterate through the `XYZ` list, get the `rollnum` out of it, and THEN compare.

In general I'd recommend having a look at `Map`. You could save the `XYZ` elements with the `rollnum` as the key, so that `someMap.get(rollNum)` gives you the corresponding `XYZ` element.